# I get an object as a string. How to convert?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

Using **IMAP** I receive an email.
But parsing, I get this:

```
{
  from: [ "name lastname <mygmail@gmail.com>" ],
  date: [ "Mon, 21 Jun 2021 13:41:51 +0500" ],
  subject: [ "hello" ]
}
```

The catch is that this is a `string`, not an object at all!
I cannot take advantage of this.
How do I convert this string to an object?

`JSON.parse()` throws an error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 141
```

Comment: what you have posted, is not a JSON string, e.g. `from` would be `"from"`

Comment: Wouldn't converting this to a string then back yield the same result? I'm fairly certain that what you're trying doesn't make sense. Just use it as an object, i.e., `imap.from` to list the from addresses etc. If you need to pass it as a payload to a REST API or similar, then use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Please add more code to show how you are receiving the string and how is it being parsed, it would help us to understand more

Comment: What you've posted there isn't IMAP, or even close to it. IMAP ⓐ doesn't use JSON and ⓑ the structure is different (from would be further subdivided into the address and the display name, for example). If this is meant to be an IMAP question, please elaborate. If not, please change the tags.

Comment: Is this something you are expecting to do?
I have copied the data you have and tried to stringyfy and parse 
https://jsfiddle.net/7yp05zqd/

Comment: @Кирилл-Достоевский would you mind marking the answer as correct if it solved your issue? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because in JSON notation properties should be enclosed in double quotes like this:

```
{
  "from": [ "name lastname <mygmail@gmail.com>" ],
  "date": [ "Mon, 21 Jun 2021 13:41:51 +0500" ],
  "subject": [ "hello" ]
}
```

So, if what you get is a string like what you showed, you'll have to add these double quotes yourself (maybe with a nice and coolio regex)

Comment: "_maybe with a nice and coolio regex_" invalid JSON and Regex don't work very well together.

Comment: @Ivar However, following the answer Ppicom I have already solved my problem.

Comment: @Ivar yeah, you're right. Maybe a `replace` for each property would work better if all properties are known. But I am curious, would you mind explaining why regex would not work? :D

Comment: @ppicom You might have JSON encoded as a string value inside of the JSON itself. Good luck finding out which keys you should add quotes to and which ones are part of a string that you should leave alone. It might be possible, but it is almost always better to fix the issue at the source. (Or here you might even consider using the JavaScript engine to parse the object, and then stringify it again.) And that is, if it _is_ actually a valid JS object. If your JSON is encoded incorrectly, who says it doesn't have other issues?

Comment: Oh right, I get you! I was assuming that the OP cannot modify the string that he's receiving.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, because this is not JSON, you can't parse it as JSON. What it does appear to be is a JavaScript snippet.

In the past `eval(customJavaScriptCode)` would have been used for this but it is **very insecure so avoid it**.

A better and safer (but not bulletproof) way is to run the JavaScript in a sandbox environment. It's hard to break out of that. You do that like this:

1. Prefix your object with `result =` , the name doesn't really matter.
2. Execute the JavaScript in a sandbox.
3. Get the value of the last statement.

```
const vm = require('vm');

const script = new vm.Script('result = ' + `{
  from: [ "name lastname <mygmail@gmail.com>" ],
  date: [ "Mon, 21 Jun 2021 13:41:51 +0500" ],
  subject: [ "hello" ]
}`);

const lastStatementResult = script.runInNewContext();

console.log(lastStatementResult.subject[0] == "hello");
```

You now have the object parsed as JS in a relatively safe way.

---

If you need more than just the last statement, you can do this like this:

```
const vm = require('vm');

const script = new vm.Script(`
  var foo = "bar";
  var baz = foo + "123";
`);

const context = {}; // will contain global variables from the script
script.runInNewContext(context);

console.log(context.foo + '123' === context.baz);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this issue following [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap) to the letter.  The problem is exactly how OP describes, there is a return value from one of Imap's callback functions that is shaped like an object, but does not respond to dot notation, nor JSON.parse/stringify.

The problem was using the suggested `inspect` property from the `util` node package.  This is what is returning a string shaped like an object that is unusable. Instead, omit the `inspect` on the values you need to parse.

#### Original usage (straight from the docs) (bad)

```
stream.once('end', function() {
  console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
});
```

#### My solution (good)

```
stream.once('end', function() {
  console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', Imap.parseHeader(buffer));
});
```

All I did was omit the `inspect`.  I can now assign `Imap.parseHeader(buffer)` to a variable and manipulate it just like a normal JS object.

Answer (score -2):

I did not understand your question correctly.

Try this

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(Object))
```

If error exist, Please describe your issue with more

Comment: Please don't answer the question if you do not understand it. If it needs more details, ask for them in the comments under the question and flag them to be closed as "Needs details or clarity".